# Добавляется только один элемент в список через адаптер

Tags: java, android, kotlin

есть переопределенный ArrayAdapter:

```
private class ContainerAdapter(ctx: Context) : ArrayAdapter<Container>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, containerList){
        override fun getView(position: Int, ConvertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            var convertView = ConvertView
            val container: Container? = getItem(position)
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null)
            }
            (convertView!!.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.text1) as TextView).text = container!!.RubbishType
            (convertView.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.text2) as TextView).text = container.Volume.toString()
            return convertView
        }
    }
```

Кнопка:

```
btnAddContainer.setOnClickListener {

            val container = Container(txtTipMusora.text.toString(), txtObjemKonteinerov.text.toString().toDouble())
            containerList.add(container)
            val adapter = ContainerAdapter(this)
            containerListView.adapter = adapter

        }
```

По нажатию кнопки почему-то добавляется только один элемент в список. Почему?

класс Container:

```
class Container(rubbishType:String = "", volume:Double = 0.0){
    val RubbishType = rubbishType
    val Volume = volume
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы каждый раз по нажатию кнопки создаете новый адаптер с одним элементом. Попробуйте инициализировать адаптер выше чем `btnAddContainer.setOnClickListener`
Или сделайте вот так :

```
containerList = mutableListOf<Container>

btnAddContainer.setOnClickListener {
            val container = Container(txtTipMusora.text.toString(),
txtObjemKonteinerov.text.toString().toDouble())
            containerList.add(container)
            containerListView.adapter = ContainerAdapter(this, containerList)
}
```

Как видите, нужно сначала добавить элемент в ваш список, а затем его предоставить адаптеру. Вообще с динамическими списками лучше использовать адаптеры, которые поддерживают notifyItemsChange() подобные методы. (почитайте)